# Refresh Client Side Web Page

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a google web app that gets information from a google spreadsheet.  If I have the web app opened in a browser, then go make a change in the spreadsheet, within the webpage, can I display some text that the page needs to be refreshed?

Comment: You want to read about [polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet?rq=1) and `window.setTimeout`/`window.setInterval`.  There's nothing on the Google server side that can "push" info to the client, the client has to ask for the information.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Polling Example:

Just copy the code and run start polling.  Click the Start Polling button.  Change the value in A1 of the active sheet and watch the sidebar.

```
function startPolling() {
  var html='<div id="msg"></div><input type="button" value="Start Polling" onClick="startPolling();" />';
  html+='<script>function startPolling(){setInterval(getA1,5000);}function getA1(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(hl){document.getElementById(\'msg\').innerHTML=hl;}).getA1();}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface); 
}

function getA1() {
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Polling');//helpful for debugging
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I’ll give this code a shot and see what happens, then let you know what I find out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Something is wrong with the code, and I am not sure how to fix it.  Secondly, does this get put into the HTML or the Code.gs

Comment: Both functions get put in the Code.gs file. I tested this before I gave it to you. It works. Follow the instructions.

Comment: if I just copy and paste it into the code.gs, I get an error.  I obviously have something different.  Sorry, I’m working on another project.  I haven’t look at the code very closely.  I’m really new to this stuff but I’m sure I’ll figure it out.

Comment: What's the error? The error code be from other code that's not formatted properly.

Comment: @bigr1822: If you want to deploy your script as a Web App and use the polling in the browser, rather than in a Spreadsheet side bar - do the following. 1. rename the `startPolling() function`  to `doGet() function` 2. Replace `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);` by `return userInterface;` 3. Deploy the script as a Web App 4. Open the web App URL in a browser window, click on 'Start Polling', see value from cell `A1` 5. Change the value in `A1` and observe how the output in the browser updates. Note: `getActiveSheet()` works only if the script is bound to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: A Sidebar still runs on the browser

Comment: @ziganotschka can you have two doGet() functions?  I assume I need to put this into that function if I already have one?  I did put it in my doGet() towards the top, and I do see the "Start Polling" button now, but do not see anything else.  All my HTML isn't being displayed.

Comment: No, if you  already have a doGet function(), please incorporate the startPolling code into it, rather than defining a second function.